# How do I write a server side node.js / express method?

Tags: javascript, express, methods, server

Let me start by saying that I come from a Meteor background where there is a clear separation of how to create and invoke client and server side methods, so I'm having some trouble grasping how things work in Express.

With that said, I am trying to:

1) Write a method that only exists on the server and is hidden from the client and returns a value to the client side.

2) Invoke said method from the client side and print/console.log the method's return value.

For example, if I have the following html for a form that takes two numbers:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstNum">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Second Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="secondNum">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Answer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer">
  </div>
  <button type="" id="calculate" name="calculate" class="btn btn-default">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

After I click calculate, I want it to send the two numbers to the server, add them, and return the value in the "Answer" textbox.

Can someone give me general guidelines on how to do so or point me to a tutorial on how to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: To send the data from the form to the server you can use an AJAX call, then calculate the result on the server and return to the browser, finally the ajax call will show the result in the manner you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set up a POST route, supplying the 2 numbers, the server then responds with the answer in the body of the response.

There is a guide on [routing in express](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) on the site, you'd use AJAX or Fetch to fire over the 2 numbers, parse the body on the server to get those numbers, do your op/s, then return the answer in the response. Once you have the response on the client then update the UI.